# Почему не виден класс в коде?

Tags: java, package

Доброго времени суток. 
Структура данных в пакетах

```
com.name
--src
----queries
------get.java
--DBConnection.class
```

Объясните, пожалуйста, почему не виден класс в коде. Есть класс синглтон для подключения к базе данных:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnection {

    private static volatile DBConnection instance;

    private DBConnection() {

    }

    public static DBConnection getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized (DBConnection.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new DBConnection();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public static Connection connection() throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/bd",
                "root",
                ""
        );
        return conn;
    }
}
```

Есть класс, которым я хочу получить доступ к синглтону, но не могу, он его не видит. В чём проблема? Он же находится в этом же пакете, или я ошибаюсь. Вот код класса, из которого хочу получить:

```
 package queries;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Get {
    public String query(String request, JSONObject data) throws SQLException {
        Connection conn = DBConnection.connection(); // Не видит класс здесь

        conn.setAutoCommit(true);

        PreparedStatement s = conn.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT * FROM users " +
                        "WHERE id > ?");
        s.setInt(1, 0);

        ResultSet result = s.executeQuery();
        while (result.next()) {
            System.out.println(result.getString("name") + " " + result.getString("email"));
        }
        return "good";
    }
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, буду очень благодарен. 
Работаю с - IDE Intellij IDEA, OS win 7, JDK 1.8.

Comment: Какая среда разработки?

Comment: intellij idea 14, windows 7, jdk 1.8

Comment: Меня вообще смущает, что ваш DBConnection уже скомпилированный отображается на одном уровне с папкой исходников (src).

Comment: По идее, у вас оба исходника классов (java) должны лежать в пакете queries. А вы, видимо, руками закинули скомпилированный класс DBConnection в корневую папку проекта. Как-то так, я полагаю.

Comment: Ну уже лежит и давно, мне интересно, почему именно так не работает. Вроде понимаю, как с пакетами работает и с импортами. Просто хотелось узнать, как именно работает с пакетами в java.

Comment: @steelhouse ну, как с пространством имен. Зоны видимости определяются соответствующим модификатором класса. Чтобы класс был виден вне пакета, используется ключевое слово public. Чтобы только в пакете - ключевое слово public отсутствует.

Comment: @steelhouse данный код не будет работать. Вы не сможете, применив имя пакета и имя класса, получить полное имя класса DBConnection. Создайте теперь в пакете queries новый класс и назовите его DBConnection - и в вашем коде (где сейчас ошибка) будет другая ошибка - не будет найден метод connection класса DBConnection. И еще, чтобы было яснее, как пакет выглядит в виде дерева каталогов, зайдите в папку src своего проекта и там все увидите. Причем заметите, что найдете файл get.java, но не найдете файла DBConnection.java.

Comment: Ну, второй ошибки нету. Метод в классе находится. Мне просто интересно, можно ли вернутся обратно в родительский каталог, грубо говоря. И как это сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Либо подключите этот скомпилированный класс как библиотеку, либо верните исходник класса на место в пакет queries.

А вот на вопрос почему так - это вам поискать, почитать.

**UPD:**

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/package.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/index.html

Книги не скажу, не заострял в них внимание на пакетах.

Comment: Я был бы признателен, если бы вы предоставили правильную литературу по этому вопросу, а не просто пойди "погугли". Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @steelhouse обновил